# How to implement a do while loop in Power Query and read the last row of a table which is updated dynamically

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to import data from sharepoint rest API using the document id of all the documents. My objective is to start from the smallest document id and move on until there are no more documents.
I have designed a custom function and i am calling it by passing the Document Id which i am starting from 0. This function return me a table containing 500 documents whose Doc Id is greater than the Document Id which i am passing.

```
#"Output" =Table.AddColumn(Termset,"c", each GetList( try List.Max(Output[c.DocId]) otherwise LastDocID))
```

So my data is updated in the Output table. My problem here is that it is returning the same set of 500 recs again and again. Which is possibly because the value of List.Max(Output[c.DocId] is not changing (i want this value to be the last document id which is returned from GetList function) . I am trying here to do someting like a do while loop.

```
do{
Output=GetList(LastDocID)
LastDocId=List.Max(Output[DocId])
}while(there_are_no_more_docs)
```

Is there any way in Power Query that i can dynamically change the value of LastDocId which i am passing to the GetList function. The method which i tried below does not seem to be working as it is not able to read the contents of the Output table after every function call. 
Note: I am using Termset as pages to put a check on the total documents being read. It is a list whose value starts from 0 and increments by 500 until it is less than the total number of docs in Sharepoint.

I would really appreciate if somebody can help me here.

Comment: Power Query is a Functional language, there's no loop. Just read all the ids or maybe in your case create them, sort them and then just add a column using the function like Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "GetList", each GetList([DocId]))

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [List.Generate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-generate) to generate all of your page requests and then compute the last document id from the list of results.

Use a loop like the following to fetch all pages from the REST API:

```
listOfPages = List.Generate(
  () => FetchPage(null),
  (page) => page <> null,
  (page) => FetchPage(page)
)
```